# how to backup and restore mailman?

Tags: centos6, mailman

How can I backup and restore mailman list ?

Our server was hacked, We plan to reload OS. We are having mailman list in server.

I'm new to mailman, It's urgent to backup and restore mailman list.

I've googled and checked this [serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/296364/how-can-i-migrate-mailman-lists-from-one-domain-to-another), They discussed about how to change mailman list from one domain to another one. But here I'm going to just backup and restore.

Please help me to solve this,

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's simple - you just backup the entire directory where mailman lives. Where that is will depend on how it was installed.

There's an instruction with scripts that can be run from cron to daily create a gzipped tarfile and mail it to a given address at [the mailman wiki](http://wiki.list.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4030694). If you don't have any other backup strategy in place, it may be useful.

Comment: I think it's installed by yum.

Comment: Regardless of how it's installed, the directory will usually be called `mailman`. You should be able to locate it by doing `find / -name mailman -type d -exec ls -ld {} \;`